# C++ How to declare function-returning function without std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Trying out some composition ideas, I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct A { };
struct B { };
struct C { };

B b4a (A a) {   B b; return b;   }
C c4b (B b) {   C c; return c;   }

template <typename R, typename S, typename T>
function<R(T)> composition
(   R(r4s)(S)
,   S(s4t)(T)   ) 
{   return [=] (T t) {   return r4s (s4t (t));  };  }

int main()
{
    cout << "b4a : " << type_name<decltype(b4a)>() << endl;
    cout << "c4b : " << type_name<decltype(c4b)>() << endl;
    auto c4a = composition<C, B, A> (c4b, b4a);
    cout << "c4a : " << type_name<decltype(c4a)>() << endl;
    auto lb4a = [=] (A a) { B b; return b; };
    auto lc4b = [=] (B b) { C c; return c; };
    auto lc4a = composition<C, B, A>(lc4b, lb4a);
    cout << "lc4a : " << type_name<decltype(lc4a)>() << endl;
}
```

(the definition of `type_name` is a bit off-topic, but you can see [a complete working sample of the above here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9bee8f7df470a03)).

You can see that this `composition` operator works for both function pointers like `b4a` and for lambdas like `lb4a`. I would like to get rid of the `function<R(T)>` return type of `composition`, and just declare its type directly, but I do not know how to denote its return type any other way. Attempting

```
R(composition)(T)
```

or

```
R(*composition)(T)
```

or

```
R(&composition)(T)
```

Produces `'composition' declared as function returning a function`, leading me to suspect it's not possible.  Clues?

Comment: While possible to do `R (*composition(R(r4s)(S), S(s4t)(T))(T)`, I can't remember if the returned pointer would be valid. In any case, it won't work because the lambda captures. Also, those parameters have extra parentheses. The first could be `R r4s(S)`, or, more commonly, `R(*r4s)(S)`.

Comment: I think you have to use `std::function` (or auto with c++1y and deduce to lambda type). you can't change captured lambda to function pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas have a unique but unspecified type.  One possible workaround is to not use lambdas, but instead, create your own equivalent class:

```
template <typename R, typename S, typename T>
struct Composition {
    R (*r4s)(S);
    S (*s4t)(T);
    R operator()(T t) const { return r4s(s4t(t)); }
};

template <typename R, typename S, typename T>
Composition<R,S,T> composition(R (*r4s)(S),S(*s4t)(T)) 
{   
    return {r4s,s4t};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create a new function at runtime. Creating a lambda simply creates an instance of the lambda's closure type (which is a class), but the function itself is created at compile time as the class's `operator()`.

The function pointers `r4s` and `s4t` captured by the lambda expression become members of the closure object. If you could truly create the composition of `r4s` and `s4t` as a new function, they would be "baked into the code", so to speak. This sort of thing is impossible to accomplish in C++.

You should use `std::function` as you do here.

Answer (score 1):

A generic, variadic variation of [@Vaughn Cato's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24297586/923854) ([Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05b5f84ae6f42a02)):

```
template <typename...>
class Composition {
    // This "base case" is only used for zero-function compositions.
public:
    void operator () () {}
};

template <typename F, typename... Remainder>
class Composition<F, Remainder...> : private Composition<Remainder...> {
    // This specialization matches all non-zero function compositions.
    using base_t = Composition<Remainder...>;

    F f_;

    // Use tag dispatching to determine if F is the last function in
    // the composition, and should be called with the args, or
    // if there are further functions and f should be called with
    // the result of passing the args on to the other functions.
    using is_last = std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof...(Remainder) == 0>;
    template <typename... Args>
    auto dispatch(std::true_type, Args&&... args) ->
      decltype(f_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
        return f_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    template <typename... Args>
    auto dispatch(std::false_type, Args&&... args) ->
      decltype(f_(std::declval<base_t&>()(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) {
        return f_(static_cast<base_t&>(*this)(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

public:
    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    Composition(T&& t, Args&&... args) :
        base_t(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
        f_(std::forward<T>(t)) {}

    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator () (Args&&... args) ->
      decltype(std::declval<Composition&>().dispatch(is_last{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
        return dispatch(is_last{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename... Functions>
inline Composition<typename std::decay<Functions>::type...>
composition(Functions&&... f)
{   
    return {std::forward<Functions>(f)...};
}
```

Comment: Wow. Lots of cool things in here I need to learn about. Most of these I can look up by name in the docs, but what is the `->` notation called in, for example, `dispatch() -> decltype()`?

Comment: @Reb.Cabin That is a [trailing return type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax), a feature introduced in C++11. It's handy because it's parsed after the declaration of the function parameters, allowing you to use parameters to formulate the return type.